# Suggestions about resistor values and additional components for this circuit?

Tags: pulse

[image]

I made the circuit above by using LTSpice where I can amplify weak, badshaped pulselike signals, shift their levels, and convert them to positive pulses. At the end I obtain a pulse train with adjustable offset and amplitude. U1 U2 U3 are universal amplifiers in LTSPice. But I am planning to use LM324 opamp for these. Here is the circuit:

Click here to see it bigger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0I5L.png

![enter image description here][2]

My question is this circuit looks ok at Spice program but I didnt implement it.

Any idead about resistor, poti values? Do I need capacitors or diodes?
Since I'm not a professional designer, I would like to have your opinions before actually solder/implement.

Comment: Don't you think it would be interesting to know what components U1,U2 and U4 are (did I just overlook U3?)?

Comment: Thanks I just edited. U1 U2 U3 are called universal amplifier in LTSpice so would be also good to have suggestions on that. the last part acts as Schmitt Trigger. I plan to use LM324 but have actually no idea if it is ok..

Comment: Why didn't you simulate with LM324 op-amps? Also, the circuit is very tiny and difficult to read.

Comment: Remove added diagram if not wanted.

Comment: @Andy aka i checked there is no LM324 in LTSpice. Click here to see it bigger:http://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Ngl.jpg

Comment: The LT1014 is compatible (and a bit better in some respects). Also the following link tells you how to import the LM324: http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/lt_spice/ltspice_lt_spice_tutorial_4.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the LM324 into LTSpice following this [link](http://www.simonbramble.co.uk/lt_spice/ltspice_lt_spice_tutorial_4.htm). Below is the section you need to read and follow: -

[image]

This will give you the simulation results that you need.

Comment: i followed your suggestions and made simulation with LM324. first two stage opams didnt change their output but the last Schmitt trigger part I needed to update the resistors as 100k to haver a nice even pulse. What could be done? it seems like i do not need any capacitors or diodes? http://i.stack.imgur.com/H0I5L.png

Comment: i mean my problem is now this might work but for optimizing would i change resistor values ect? would you suggests 100k resistors instead. i cannot see the difference in simulations but in other perspectives i caouldnt decide

Comment: You will need power supply capacitors - use 10nF for each rail per quad op-amp and maybe a bulk capacitor of 10uF for each rail. If you are happy with the simulation, what resistor values do you think need changing and why. If you are going to design a circuit board there is always the possibility of resistor values changing due to "unforeseen problems" and simulation weaknesses.